# Client is asking for a copy of my contract to let me enter into their offices

Tags: ethics, contracts, clients, consulting

I work in a consulting company and I currently work with the client, who is asking me a copy of my contract. I scanned and sent my contract with some of the information hidden (income and personal address). But they are still refusing it because of the hidden information.

Is it really necessary? This is only for the purpose of getting me an access card. I understand physical security has to be taken very seriously. But they are still not accepting the copy I sent unless I show them 100% of the information.

As far as I know, I am not supposed to disclose my personal information. Should I just send it to the client?

Guess I should speak with my manager and HR.

Comment: "*Guess I should speak with my manager and HR*" Any reason why you didn't do that before posting this? The general question is very broad and the typical answer would be "pass it up the chain".

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your company should be dealing with this. So pass it on to them.

The client should NOT be dealing direct with you in anything not immediately relevant to your tasks. You shouldn't even have scanned in the document the first time. Email all correspondence to your manager to deal with. If the client asks, tell them that your company is dealing with it and give them your managers contact email.

Comment: Thank you, I was worried because it's been a week and I've been working from home, which personally I don't like.

Comment: @Ching you've been working from home for a week without speaking to your manager about the situation??

Comment: @Ching: I would highly suggest that the next time you hit a roadblock you talk to your management immediately.  Waiting a week for something this simple would be a huge black mark against you in my organization.

Comment: Actually, I was waiting for an internal guy to do all the paperwork. Everyone knew I was working from home. Everything went well, HR sent to the client a new document with the relevant information.